# Smarty, get values from array, using loop to step between keys

Tags: php, smarty

In my last thread i did not explain myself correctly... i use Smarty v2.5
I need to get values for array `$myArray[0]` which are under `var1, var2, var3...` keys

```
{section name="myLoop" start=1 loop=100}

   $myArray[0].var{$smarty.section.myLoop.index}

{/section}
```

i need to make result string actually get array value like if i use

```
{$myArray[0].var1}
{$myArray[0].var2}
{$myArray[0].var3}
etc.
```

Comment: You should have edited your original question rather than ask the same thing but in a different way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the smarty docs:

```
{$foo.$bar}   <-- display variable key value of an array, similar to PHP $foo[$bar]
```

Haven't tested, but I would do:

```
{section name="myLoop" start=1 loop=100}
    {assign var="key" value="var".$smarty.section.myLoop.index}
    {$myArray[0].$key}
{/section}
```

Comment: `{for}` does not exist in v2.x; it needs to be `{section}`.

Answer (score 0):

I think {for} works, but {$foo.$bar} is for v3 and does not work on v2.5